# Efficiently rendering tiled map using SpriteKit

Tags: cocoa, swift, opengl, sprite-kit

As an exercise, I decided to write a SimCity (original) clone in Swift for OSX. I started the project using SpriteKit, originally having each tile as an instance of `SKSpriteNode` and swapping the texture of each node when that tile changed. This caused terrible performance, so I switched the drawing over to regular Cocoa windows, implementing `drawRect` to draw `NSImage`s at the correct tile position. This solution worked well until I needed to implement animated tiles which refresh very quickly.

From here, I went back to the first approach, this time using a texture atlas to reduce the amount of draws needed, however, swapping textures of nodes that need to be animated was still very slow and had a huge detrimental effect on frame rate.

I'm attempting to display a 44x44 tile map where each tile is 16x16 pixels. I know here must be an efficient (or perhaps more correct way) to do this. This leads to my question:

Is there an efficient way to support 1500+ nodes in SpriteKit and which are animated through changing their textures? More importantly, am I taking the wrong approach by using SpriteKit and `SKSpriteNode` for each tile in the map (even if I only redraw the dirty ones)? Would another approach (perhaps, OpenGL?) be better?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'd be happy to provide code samples, but I'm not sure how relevant/helpful they would be for this question.

**Edit**
Here are some links to relevant drawing code and images to demonstrate the issue:

Screenshot:
[image: Swiftopolis]

When the player clicks on the small map, the center position of the large map changes. An event is fired from the small map the central engine powering the game which is then forwarded to listeners. The code that gets executed on the large map the change all of the textures can be found here:

https://github.com/chrisbenincasa/Swiftopolis/blob/drawing-performance/Swiftopolis/GameScene.swift#L489

That code uses `tileImages` which is a wrapper around a Texture Atlas that is generated at runtime.

https://github.com/chrisbenincasa/Swiftopolis/blob/drawing-performance/Swiftopolis/TileImages.swift

Please excuse the messiness of the code -- I made an alternate branch for this investigation and haven't cleaned up a lot of residual code that has been hanging around from pervious iterations.

Comment: youre rendering 1500+ nodes and updating all of them?  That's going to be hard on performance..   You probably need to optimize your code.  Only update the visible tiles maybe?

Comment: @hamobi 1500+ nodes are visible. Each node represents a single tile, at the moment: 44x44 = 1936 nodes visible. The worst case is updating all of them (for example, when the map is scrolled). I'm wondering if there is an efficient way to update all of these or if it would be better to use a different framework that would be more performant for this use case.

Comment: Are you doing some kind of collision or other kind of calculation per frame that might not need to be done ? Iterating through 1936 nodes and checking something, might very well cause problems. Multiple iterations per frame even worse. have you tried just a rendering test ?

Comment: Ok, did a quick rendering test with 44x44 grid with 1936 animated 16x16 SKSpriteNodes  all animating at the same time on OSX. Got a solid 60fps on a macbook pro - 2012 model. I doubt that your issue is rendering given that test, unless you are testing on a lesser machine.

Comment: My guess is that there is a large amount of ai running per frame that can likely be managed better. You also might want to profile your game to get an idea of how much frame time a given block of code is eating.

Comment: @prototypical there is no AI running, I turn off the simulation when profiling. How did you animate the nodes? The "animation" I mention here involves changing each node's texture, as each image is a separate frame in the animation. I think this is where my overheard may be coming from, so my question is methods to work around this technique.

Comment: I guess showing your animation code would be helpful too. Are you using SKActions, using some sort of delta time, and are you creating the textures as you need them or do you create the texture once? does each tile create its own texture or do you get it from some sort of texture manager class?

Comment: how do you determine when to change an animation etc ? I just used a SKAction that constantly repeated animations on each node. Trying to tackle this issue in this manner is what I call coding charades. Having the code would allow someone to help you far more efficiently. github it.

Comment: @prototypical I have added a screenshot and links to some files on Github. Feel free to look at the other files in the project if they will help.

Comment: @SkylerLauren I updated the original post with some information and links to the repository that has the code for this (specifically linking to particular lines)

Comment: Project builds but has runtime error in TileGenerator/main.swif  I'm guessing it doesn't have all the files it needs. They are possibly dynamically linked on your machine.

Comment: @prototypical my apologies -- I commented out lines in a build script that didn't need to run on every compile. I pushed up a new commit to the master branch. https://github.com/chrisbenincasa/Swiftopolis/commit/c0a3deee713fd08b0d127ae4bae0daaf499d9923

Comment: @prototypical I'm fairly certain this was the error you were experiencing. If not, please let me know. Sorry for the trouble. Also, please note that the changes I described in the edited description are on the "drawing-performance" branch, not the "master" branch.

Comment: @prototypical I tested that build worked correctly by checking out a clean version of master and building with `xcodebuild -target Swiftopolis -configuration Debug` on the command line (from within the root project directory

Comment: yep, runs for me now. Is it your intention to have the scrolling to happen a tile in a given direction at a time as opposed to a smooth scrolling ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72686/discussion-between-prototypical-and-christian-benincasa).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will "answer" your question, but may help.

SpriteKit will likely be able to handle what you need but you need to look at different optimizations for SpriteKit and more so your game logic.

SpriteKit. Creating a .atlas is by far one of the best things you can do and will help keep your draw calls down. Also as I learned the hard way keep a pointer to your SKTextures as long as you need them and only generate the ones you needs. For instance don't create textureWithImageNamed@"myImage" every time you need a texture for myImage instead keep reusing a texture and store it in a dictionary. Also `skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;` helps a bunch but you have to manage your own zPosition on all the sprites.

Game logic. Updating every tile every loop is going to be very expensive. You will want to look at a better way to do that. keeping smaller arrays or maybe doing logic (model) updates on a background thread.

I currently have a project you can look into if you want called [Old Frank](https://github.com/Urthstripe29/Old-Frank). I have a map that is 75 x 75 with 32px by 32px tiles that may be stacked 2 tall. I have both Mac and iOS target so you could in theory blow up the scene size and see how the performance holds up. Not saying there isn't optimization work to be done (it is a work in progress), but I feel it might help get you pointed in the right direction at least.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll definitely have a look at your project. I currently do have an .atlas file which did help a lot by reducing the amount of draws I needed to make each frame. The game simulation is run on a separate thread, but I disable that when testing rendering performance. I'll most certainly look into "ignoresSiblingOrder" as well, as the tiles don't need to be stacked in any way.